# Unhandled promise rejection(gas limit) when deploying Contract to rinkeby using truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, rinkeby, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I am trying to Deploy a beginners contract onto the rinkeby test network through Infura node. It is throwing the following error.

```
(node:35183) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit.
(node:35183) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

    contract Inbox {
        string public message;

        function Inbox(

string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    } }
```

I used some console logs to determine where the error is being thrown, I have marked it below with a //COMMENT.

Deploy script

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'word frog gentle happy chicken book sneeze provide stick handle four fan',
      'https://rinkeby.infura.io/myStringOfRandomLetters'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to Deploy from account', accounts[0]);

//ERROR OCCURS HERE
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
        .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Things I have tried to fix it:

Increasing the gas limit to 2,000,000, 4,000,000 and decreasing to around 500,000 and 21,000. I hit a "too small amount of gas" error, so I know gas amount is not the issue.

It may have been the npm module "truffle-hdwallet-provider" not installing properly, so I uninstalled, then sudo installed, then found the error fix on the internet (add --unsafe-perm to the commmand). like below

`$ sudo npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider --unsafe-perm`

still same error. I noticed another identical question [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-please-check-your-gas-limit) however (as of now)it is also unanswered.

Comment: this `Deploy` script you're using - what is that? Is that another file? Cause all the tutorials I've seen say you're supposed to be doing all this using the `truffle.js` file. And then doing a Migrate in `Terminal` to get all this deployed. So what are you doing?

Comment: @Sirab33 the code I'v posted abpove is a deployment script. the actually deployment happens in
`const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
        .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

 `
It uses `HDWalletProvider` to connect to an infura node, which web3 uses to deploy through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added `'0x' +` in front of the bytecode in the `.deploy` to make it Work.

`.deploy({ data: '0x' + bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })`

If there's no `'0x'` the bytecode will convert the whole string to hexadecimal, which will be double the size and throw the gas error.

I also re-installed truffle wallet provider using

`$ sudo uninstall truffle-hdwallet-provider`

and then

`$ sudo install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider` when inside my project folder.

I also updated git by following [this tutorial](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-please-check-your-gas-limit)

This answer is inspired from the answer [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-please-check-your-gas-limit)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the '0x' to the bytecode worked for me, didn't need to reinstall the wallet provider.For some reason when I didn't add the '0x' to the bytecode, the I ended up using all the gas.

If you check https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ and scan for the account you used to deploy, it will clearly show how much gas has been used. before the '0x' it shows that all gas was used up (3,000,000 gas), but after the '0x' is added it shows 281,572 gas has been used.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Compiler = require('./Compiler');
const HDwalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const {interface,bytecode} = Compiler.parse('Inbox');
const walletProvider = new HDwalletProvider('Mnemonic','Rinkeby_link');
const web3 = new Web3(walletProvider);

async function deploy(){
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log('Deploying from Contract : ',accounts[0]);
  let details = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface)).deploy({data:'0x'+bytecode,arguments:['Msg for rinkeby']}).send({from:accounts[0],gas:'3000000'});
  console.log(details.options.address);
}
deploy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need one `await` on `deploy(...)` and one `await` on `send(...)`.

Something like this:

```
let x = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface));
let y = await x.deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] });
let z = await y.send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });
console.log('Contract deployed to', z.options.address);
```

And it looks like you also need an `await` on the call to `deploy()`, since this is an `async` function.

Comment: I added all your code, no change. When I added an await to the deploy(); at the bottom, it threw an error of "unexpected identifier". So I deleted it. I'm still lost, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure its due to latest version 0.0.5 of truffle-hdwallet-provider.
If you uninstall it and reinstall version 0.0.3, this problem won't appear and you can go on the Udemy course.

Comment: I was wrong initally, there is version 0.0.3 avaliable. I have tried up update it and it cannot install. I will update my git and see if it works then.

Comment: I can't install 0.0.3. Instead I just added a  `'0x' +` inside the data tag of `.deploy`. As seen in this answer [HERE](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/error-the-contract-code-couldnt-be-stored-please-check-your-gas-limit)

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the bytecode was too large. Deleting all the inline comments worked for me.